# How to use Ubuntu Desktop as a Web Server

Tags: server

These are the details of what I am trying to do:

I am currently using an HP laptop with a hard drive, with Ubuntu Desktop installed on it(dual-booting with windows). How can I host an online web server(accessible over the internet) WITHOUT messing up my existing Ubuntu GUI System where all my work and apps are stored? I want it to be running continuously even while I am working on my system, and it would also be good if it didn't mess up my dual-boot Windows System.

I plan on installing a LAMP Stack and using the server for website projects.

Comment: Sorry but a server has no gui.

Comment: Without hardware specs this is not a question that can be answered. Having said that this question calls for an opinion which is off topic on this site. It is not practical to run a full time web site on a laptop which is also your own dual booted workstation.

Comment: A broad answer to a broad question: step 1 would be to install LAMP, step 2 to (possibly) configure your router to accept incoming requests and to forward them to your HP laptop, and then you're in business.

Comment: As @Jos says, install the very same packages as you would on Ubuntu Server. Both Ubuntu Desktop and Server use the very same packages for this. That said, if you dual-boot, be aware that your web server will disappear when you’re running Windows. Do you need a solution that will work in both Ubuntu *and* Windows? 

Comment: @nobody While Ubuntu Server installation indeed has no GUI, there's nothing that prevents you from installing web server software (or any other server software, for example ssh server) on a regular Ubuntu Desktop installation with GUI.

Comment: Your server also won't run when your Ubuntu system is asleep/suspended.

Comment: Basically it would be way better if I used an old laptop and installed Ubuntu Server on it, right?